# Can open SFTP connection via WinSCP, but cannot with JSch

Tags: java, jboss7.x, sftp, jsch

I am trying to connect to a remote device that I cannot manage via a JSch, although I can connect using WinSCP client with the same credentials.

The application is a J2EE based enterprise application, which runs on JBoss AS 7.1.1, on a Windows server, and I am trying to connect the SFTP server from a Quartz job. The code that I am using to verify SFTP login is below.

```
try {
    Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", 22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setPassword("password");
    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;                
    channel.connect();
    session.disconnect();
    channelSftp.disconnect();

} catch (JSchException e) {
    log("Cannot make connection to FTP server ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>   exception at session.connect();

I am using 0.1.50 version of JSch

Another inconsistency occurs when I ran this code in development environment; I can connect to a server with SFTP.

Can you help me pinpoint the probable cause of this behavior?

Comment: Sharing your WinSCP configuration or even better a WinSCP log file may help.

Comment: Thank you @MartinPrikryl, the issue was solved but I forgot to add a comment unfortunately. It was happening because of some permission issue.

Comment: So please submit the resolution as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was because of the topology of the network and permissions of the communicating parties. If you face the same problem, please take these issues in to consideration.